# Array methods for find a word in Javascirpt

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm stuck working on something and need help. I want to find a word in a path and use it as an object.

I mean, there is array like this;

```
routes : [
   0: {
      ...
       path : 'x/x/create'
      ... }
   1: {
     ...
     path : 'y/y/y'
     ... }
]
```

and I want to use object with path : 'x/x/create'. And of course it s not always in the first place.
*Edit: x always changing so I need to find 'create' word

Comment: Try it with [Array find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
routes.find(i => i.path.includes('create')).word;
```

Comment: thnk u for answering but x letter always changing,  ıt can be a/a/create or b/create etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Array.find`

```js
const routes = [
  { path: 'x/x/create' },
  { path: 'y/y/y' },
]
console.log(routes.find((route) => route.path === 'x/x/create'));
console.log(routes.find((route) => route.path === '/create'));
```

Comment: thnk u for answering but x letter always changing,  It can be a/a/create or b/create etc.

Comment: @EbruEsra is it just `something/create`? or any specific pattern? If its just `something/create` you can just check with `routes.find((route) => route.path === '/create')`. Or if any specific pattern, please specify.

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    path: "x/x/create"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    path: "y/y/y"
  }
]

const result = routes.find(i => {
  if (i.path.split('/')[2] === 'create') return i.id;
});

console.log(result); //{id:1, path:"x/x/create"}
```